Simulatability of random variables
Let $(X, \mathcal F_X, P)$ be a probability space and $(Y, \mathcal F_Y)$ a measurable space. I say that a probability $P'$ on $(Y, \mathcal F_Y)$ is simulatable by $P$ if there exists a measurable map $f : X \to Y$ such that $P'$ is the pushforward of $P$ by $f$ -- that is,
$$P'(E) = P(f^{-1}(E)),$$
for all $E \in \mathcal F_Y$.
My question: What are sufficient and necessary conditions on $X$ and $Y$ such that all probabilities $P'$ on $Y$ are simulatable by $X$?
I believe that it is sufficient for $X$ to be a standard probability space and $Y$ a Polish space (or more generally a Souslin space) with $\mathcal F_Y$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Are either of these two conditions necessary?
I realise that this might not be worded correctly. (It's quite likely that there is already a term for what I'm calling ``simulatable''.) Answers which direct to relevant literature will be appreciated.
